# Seeing dead process in nethogs?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, traffic

nethogs is a very useful tool to see which process(es) send/receive lots of network traffic. But as soon as the process exits, on the next display refresh nethogs no longer displays the process. Is there a way to tell nethogs to keep the information of dead processes for a while, or a simple way to capture this information?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34483/arnout-engelen, He is author of NetHogs. you may ping him in chat

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to search him on chat.stackexchange.com or find a link on the above page to start a chat with him. Probably my reputation is not enough or something. I'll contact him via other means.

Comment: just ping him in chat.stackexchange.com by @ followed by his account name. if he was near around here, he will feedback

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the tracemode (-t) gives me information I need.